# Read password protected Google site with Python

Tags: python, google-play

I want to read the HTML contents of a site on Google's Play Store developer backend from Python. 
The Url is

```
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=1234567890#AppListPlace
```

The site is of course only accessibly if you're logged in.

I naively tried:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username@gmail.com', 'mypassword'))
```

which yielded only the default 'you need to be logged in to view this page' html content.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to read the HTML contents of the page is not the way to go.

Basic HTTP authentication is not something you will see very often these days. It's the kind which pops up a browser alert message asking you for your username and password. Google, like most other websites, uses their own more sophisticated system. That system is not designed to be accessed by anyone but humans. Not to mention that storing your Google account password in your source code is a terrible idea.

Instead, you should look into the [Google Play Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html), which *is* designed to be accessed by machines, and uses OAuth2 authentication.

Comment: Makes sense. 
Unfortunately the official API doesn't quite let me do what I want to do. Thanks though.